# Android achartengine set axes step

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using achartengine to display a line chart. The y axis shows the number of times an advert  has been viewed so it doesn't make sense to have y axis labels that are not whole numbers. If the max number of advert views in the range is 3 or more then it works fine as the y axis label go up in steps of 1 e.g. 0,1,2,3. However if the max number of advert views is less than 3 you get y axis labels 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 etc or 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1 etc. Is there any way to set the minimum step of the axis labels to 1 or tell it to only show whole number axis labels.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the minimum step, but there is a way to indicate about how many nice numbers you want for labels. If your data range is lower than 3, then you can do something like:

```
renderer.setYLabels(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this didn't actually solve my issue as I still had non-whole y label values. However setting the max y value in the setRange method to 3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the max y value to 3 in the setRange method if the actual max y value is less than 3.